# Incorporating expanded crit-range into anydice?

Tags: dnd-5e, anydice

Not sure if this is a valid "tools" question, but here goes: I want to compare a build that can attack 5 times, with a 5% critical chance; to a build that can attack 3 times, but with a 15% critical chance. How can I do this in anydice? Assume each attack in the first case is 1d6 + 5, and 2d6 + 5 in the second case.

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad. Without the effect of a critical in the question the dnd-5e tag is still required.

Comment: There's no way to really compare the two without assuming to-hit numbers. E.g. if only natural 20 hits the former deals 67% more damage on average, while if 18 and up hit (and nothing else) it only deals 10% more.

Comment: @Hassassin While you're technically right, that's an extreme case--one that doesn't even exist. A Tarrasque, **designed for a Level 30 party,** has an AC of 25... so, **any L20 char** that maxed their main stat and uses a non-magical weapon with proficiency will hit on a 14 or more.

Comment: @Khashir, my point is that the relative damage output depends on the hit chance. Those were just two numbers I could calculate in my head. Real probability graphs look something like [this](http://anydice.com/program/4a88) (based on Miniman's answer).

Comment: @Hassassin: Fair enough, it's an interesting refinement, thank you. It seems like it doesn't affect the answer except when PC's have to roll >14 (which, right now, is a non-issue, per my comment above). But it's still good to keep in mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was my first try at using anydice.

The results for the first build are here: http://anydice.com/program/4a60

The results for the second build are here: http://anydice.com/program/4a62

The comparison between the two is here: http://anydice.com/program/4a63

I'll include the comparison graph for the sake of having something other than a link in this answer:

[image: comparison graph]

(For those who don't want to zoom in, the black line is the first build, and the orange one is the second.)

Comment: You are assuming anything that isn't critical hit deals normal damage. At least a natural 1 will deal none, probably other low numbers.

Comment: The question doesn't take into account the possibility of missing, so neither did I.