# At what AC does GWM become ineffective?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, optimization

For the mathematically challenged (me), is there a general, simple, easy-to-remember rule of thumb for when a monster's AC is high enough that you should not use GWM because the -5 to hit becomes too much of a handicap? i.e. Rule of Thumb: Don't use GWM against an opponent with an AC higher than 'X'? Or are there too many variables to make a general rule? If it matters, assume a strength-based generic mid level player with a +4 or +5 to hit.

Comment: Reckless Attack is a barbarian ability that lets you get advantage on attacks in exchange for giving enemies advantage to attack you. There's no -5 involved at all.  Were you thinking of the Great Weapon Master feat? (Also, by  mid levels a +5 to hit is pretty pathetic, by that point you should probably be at +3 to +5 primary ability plus a +3 or +4 prof bonus...)

Comment: If you are looking for GWM/SS, this is a pretty good video and explains the math. The video is about BG3, but it references how to do the math in 5e. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rx4tSn6vbA8

Comment: If this question is about GWM/SS, then [this question on the mathematical soundness of the feature](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76631/are-features-that-allow-%e2%88%925-to-attack-to-get-10-to-damage-mathematically-sound) is a likely duplicate.